# Select dropdown using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

Usually I use the selenium Select object like this:

```
val selectCode = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("someID")))
selectCode.selectByValue("4")
```

my issue is that I dont have value in the html code, this is the button html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="admin-select-page" title="Select..."><span class="filter-option pull-left">Select...</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button>
```

and this is the value I need to select:

```
<li data-original-index="4" data-optgroup="2"><a tabindex="0" class="opt  " style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">
Invoices
</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
```

But as you can see above I usually have id and value so the By.id or By.value will work...

How do I select it in this case..?

thanks!

Comment: best way is selecty by xpath or cssSelector. But I cannot give you example of xpath as there is not enough of hmtl code to give you correct xpath...

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath for locating element.

```
driver.findElement(By.(xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Select...')]/li[contains(text(),'Invoices')]")
```

Here, text() function is used for finding the element which contains some text inside tag.

Answer (score 0):

For me always work this code (it's small and useful):

```
new Select(driver.findElement(yourElement)).selectByVisibleText("Txt");
```

In Page Object (+PageFactory) it would be like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//select[@name='filter_state']") //for example
private WebElement dropdownList;
 private void selectStatus(String selectText){
    new Select(dropdownList).selectByVisibleText(selectText);
}
```